# Is it possible to achieve HA using the rabbitmq-server juju charm?

Tags: juju, rabbitmq

Is it possible to achieve HA using the rabbitmq-server juju charm? Is it possible to have mastar/slaves? Hot Standby, like the PostgreSQL charm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a branch dedicated to the development of rabbitmq-server that supports mirrored queues:

https://code.launchpad.net/~openstack-charmers/charms/precise/rabbitmq-server/active-active

See iif this can help you